# Adding pre-made vlc-qt widgets to qt designer

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt-designer, vlc-qt

I have downloaded binary version of vlc-qt (VLC-Qt for Windows 64-bit (MSVC 2012)) from this link :
http://vlc-qt.tano.si/

I want to add its widgets to qt designer but I don't know how. I could not find any instructions or a "read me".

Comment: I don't see any evidence that vlc-qt provides a designer plugin, which would explain why you cannot find the instructions/readme. I would suggest you look at the [examples](https://github.com/vlc-qt/examples) to see how to use the library.

Comment: i opend the test-widgets example TestPlayer.ui file and there is a widget called video and its class is "VlcWidgetVideo" . when i open that ui file in designer i can see that widget but ofcourse it has errorrs(because there is no video widget in my designer ) .

Comment: I don't know where you're getting the TestPlayer.ui file from. I opened [SimplePlayer.ui](https://github.com/vlc-qt/examples/blob/master/simple-player/src/SimplePlayer.ui) in Qt Designer without seeing any errors, and it shows all the VLC widgets. The example uses [widget promotion](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html#promoting-widgets) to add the VLC classes.

Comment: Improved readability.

Comment: widget promotion it is ! . that works now . tnx .